# How to force VSCode to use Python 3 instead of Python 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-3.7

Using macOS.

I'm using VSCode 1.28.2 and I am wondering how I can force VSCode to use Python 3 instead of Python 2. Unless I use the shebang: `#!/usr/bin/env python3` , I always get an ImportError or some other problem, even though the intrepreter is using Python 3.7.

Image here:

[image: Python 3.7 interpreted selected but importError]

If I use the shebang, the code works and the output in the Terminal is:

`<bound method Response.raise_for_status of <Response [200]>>`

I am using the Python Extension by Microsoft.(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [issue 2125](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2125) which mentions:

> By default, a local `pipenv` environemnt is searched for and if found, is marked as the python interpreter. But it also then adds a line to settings.json indicating the path for the virtual environment which can cause issues for configs shared among a team.

That same issue includes the following workaround:

> a work-around for this is to set `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT` and the extension will automatically pick up the `.venv` directory that gets created.
>   And you can set `python.pythonPath` to `${workspaceFolder}/.venv` to be consistent within your project without any hard-coded, absolute paths.

That could help set a default python version.

Answer (score 3):

In code-runner.executorMap I updated:

- `"python": "python -u",` to
- `"python": "python3 -u",`

Then I reloaded my window and it worked!

Comment: Thanks a ton! This was giving me problems on Mac for a longer time.