# VSCode running Python 2 instead of 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I am using Python with VSCode, and if I use Cmd+Shift+P and type Run Code, it runs the code with Python2 even though I have specified it to use Python3. I have read this tutorial:
[How to force VSCode to use Python 3 instead of Python 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53110324/how-to-force-vscode-to-use-python-3-instead-of-python-2)
but I do not understand how to change it. (and I can't comment because I don't have enough reputation yay)
Could anyone help? Thanks!

Maybe it could be related to the fact that the mini terminal at the bottom runs "python -u " instead of "python3 -u "? Does anyone know how to change that?

Comment: Maybe you need to set `python.pythonPath` to the path of the folder with `python3` in it. See the VSCode [Settings Reference for Python](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference).

Comment: I have tried that, but it still runs Python 2.

Comment: Possibly relevant: Notice what the author shows as the contents of their config file in the question [How to add a command line option to Python execution in vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54139624/how-to-add-a-command-line-option-to-python-execution-in-vscode). Apparently that's where you can specify the path to the python3 interpreter.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please note the command `Run Code` is not provided by the Python Extension for VS Code, instead it is provided by the extension [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner). They are two separate extensions. 
You'll need to configure that extension to point to the Python Interpter you have chosen.
I.e. as per their docs on the home page you have to update the settings:

```js
{
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "python": "<fully qualified path>",
    }
}
```

Or you have another solution, that's to use the command `Python: Run Python file in Terminal`. This does not rely on the `Code Runner` extension and is part of the `Python Extension` hence using the interpreter you have selected.

Comment: How do you open the settings as a JSON file please, I can only get to the settings and there doesn't seem to be a way to make terminal use python 3 in there

Comment: Such an extension should be able to check which python version is in use and use that to run the file in question!

Comment: Took a while to find my way to this answer. After specifying Python 3 "everywhere", putting this into settings.json was THE way to get Run Code (CTRL+ALT+N) to recognize that I was writing Python 3 code...

Answer (score 7):

Try changing the selected Python environment.

[image: select-python-interpreter]

This can be accessed by

1. Clicking on the Python label at the lower-left of the window
2. Doing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Mac) OR <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Windows/Linux)
3. Selecting *Select Interpreter*

Select Python3 instead of Python2 from the dropdown.

More info here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment

> An "environment" in Python is the context in which a Python program
> runs.
>
> Selecting an interpreter from the list adds an entry for
> `python.pythonPath` with the path to the interpreter inside your
> [Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings). Because the path is part of the workspace
> settings, the same environment should already be selected whenever you
> open that workspace.
>
> The Python extension uses the selected environment for running Python
> code (using the **Python: Run Python File in Terminal** command),
> providing language services (auto-complete, syntax checking, linting,
> formatting, etc.) when you have a `.py` file open in the editor, and
> opening a terminal with the **Terminal: Create New Integrated Terminal**
> command. In the latter case, VS Code automatically activated the
> selected environment.

Comment: Hmm, I have tried that, but it still doesn't work? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

As @Don mentioned in his answer the `Run Code` command is provided by the [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension not by the [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) one.
Anyway, You can simply add the following to your `settings.json` file:

```
{
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "python": "python3 -u"
    }
}
```

P.S: You need to reload your vs code after doing this so simply hit `Ctrl + Shift + P` and run `Reload Window`.

Answer (score -2):

Did you check your system enviroment variables? Maybe Pyhton 2 is in your PATH instear of Python 3. You should consider uninstalling Python 2 from your PC if It's not going to be missed... I was having a similar trouble working with Machine Learn and it solved for me.

Comment: Hmm, but I read a few other answers on stack overflow saying deleting an Apple provided version of Python may break the entire OS, so I don't really want to do that.

Comment: Don't remove (or even considering removing) the system Python. Mac and Linux-like OS'es use it for system-related operations.