# Visual Studio Code not recognizing pip packages installed?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-docx, python-venv

So I set up a virtual environment via Python3 -m venv in the folder that I am working in on Visual Studio code. I can successfully run my script when I run it from the terminal (either on visual studio or outside of visual stuidio. When I run 'which Python3' on the terminal (after being in the virtual environment directory), I get back: /Users/User/Documents/Udemy_Python_Course/env/bin/Python3, which is the location that I created the virtual environment in. Therefore, I have set that path as my path with Visual studio code but it is not recognizing the module that I installed (python-docx) on the virtual environment when I run from Visual studio. Anyone have any ideas, I've been trying to solve this one for over a day? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you positive that your VSC interperter on the bottom left is set to the virtual env? I see this all the time, it is easy for it pointing to somewhere else, like your base installation

Comment: Yes it is set to 3.8.2 64-bit('env': venv).

Comment: @JamesNorris 
Hmm, after activating the virtual environment in vscode terminal, 
Run: `pip list`
Does the required package show up there?

Comment: Yes sir, Python-docx is showing up fine in the pip list both in the virtual environment on VSCode terminal and personal computer terminal. The path list that I'm using is based on what the /env folder has listed as follows: VIRTUAL_ENV="/Users/JamesN/Documents/Udemy_Python_Course/env"
export VIRTUAL_ENV ; So that's why I'm using Users/JamesN/Documents/Udemy_Python_Course/env. Is it possible this is not the correct path? I'm also using the extension Coderunner for VScode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more time spent combing and researching, I actually found another post here on Stackexchange that explained the source of the problem.

Though my path was set up correctly in the settings.json tab for VSCode and VSCode recognized my virtual environment, the Extension 'Code Runner' was simply set to look for 'Python' which for some reason was defaulting to Macs standard Python 2.7 installation. I changed the path that this extention looks for to my current path: 'env/bin/python' instead of simply Python and alas, it can now run in VSCode and with the terminal.

Before:

```
    {
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "python": "<Python>",
    }
}
```

After:

```
{
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "python": "env/bin/python",
    }
}
```

Credit to: Don for his resolution listed here: [VSCode running Python 2 instead of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54299927/vscode-running-python-2-instead-of-3/54322098)

Thanks to those who offered there help!